# What word can I use to describe a relationship between one person and their half-sibling's half-sibling?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

Amy is the daughter of Bob and Carol.
Bob and Carol, at some point in their lives, married Chelsey and Dan, respectively.
Egbert is the son of Chelsey and Bob, while Fabio is the son of Carol and Dan.

Egbert is Fabio's _____.

Comment: So what kind of relationship are you wanting to convey other than that they are siblings?

Answer (score 0):

[***Stepsibling***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibling#3.2F4_sibling)

> "Stepsiblings" (stepbrothers or stepsisters) are the children of one's stepparent from a previous relationship. They are unrelated by blood.

Comment: What about the children of one's stepparent from a marriage that occurred after the stepparent's divorce from one's biological parent?

Comment: so just the step-sibling of a step-sibling or also the half-sibling of a half-sibling and the half-sibling of a step sibling? This actually applies to me and my kin.

Comment: Step-sister once removed (or twice removed, or thrice removed, depending on the promiscuity of Bob and his ilk. (Who would have children with someone called Chelsey by the way?)